# What's the Correct Way of Saving Macro Enabled Excel File?

Tags: excel, save, vba

it's my 6th day with vba excel and i'm trying to learn things as long as i need for my report formatting tool development task which is almost done. The thing that bothers me is each time i try to save my changes on visual basic editor and excel, it gives a bunch of error messages. I'm very sick of it, and my nerves about the break.

The question is as I say in the title: What's the Correct Way of Saving Macro Enabled Excel File?

Comment: What error messages do you get ? What version of Excel ? In 2007 you should save in .xslm.

Comment: Here's another tip: In the VBE, you can also select `Debug > Compile` in the on the menu bar. This will check the syntax of your code and alert you when things are out of whack. This will not stop run-time errors, necessarily, but it's a huge step in helping you learn to write code and stop errors from happening. The more you compile in the begining, the less surprises you will have and the faster you will learn how to write.

Comment: Check the procedures you might have in:  `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)`

Comment: First of all, thank you everybody for your comments.

@t.thielemans : It was already saved as .xlsm file.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman : Thanks for advice, from now i'm gonna apply it

Comment: @CaBieberach : Nope. It doesn't exist in my code

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur : As i said to t.thielemans , It was already saved as .xlsm file. But from now i'm gonna take snapshot of every error message to show issues of xlsm file saving

Comment: @TimurAykutYıldırım, didn't see Alexandre already posted that. It's best to post examples of your errors and be complete, that'll help solve your problem. In your question you don't state it's saved as `.xlsm` ;)

Comment: @t.thielemans sorry, i wasn't saying it agressively :) (a)